# what is the difference among these terminologies in web applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

i wanna to ask what is the difference among these terminologies? in details

### 1-Post back

### 2-auto post back

### 3- submit

### 4- refresh(F5)

### 5- request the same URL

### 6- AJAX call

thanks

Comment: Did you just rip this question straight from an exam?

Comment: sure not,, i wanna to know the technical differences among them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Action on the HTML form results
   which submits the form to the same URL.
2. Action like selection in drop
   down box results in Post back.
3. Html form is sent to the
   specified URL.
4. Resend last HTTP request.
5. New HTTP GET request for the same
   URL.
6. Asynchronnous call to a server
   which does not result in reloading
   the whole page but instead modify
   only part of the page. User can work
   with the page when call is
   processed.

These were just very general descriptions.

Comment: No 4: F5 requests the same page, not specifically using `GET` but will also attempt to re-`POST` where the current page is the result from a `POST`.  No. 5: The answer to this is what you put for No. 4.

Comment: You are right, it was my mistake. I have modified answer so it should be correct now.